# Перевернуть матрицу

Tags: javascript, матрицы

Есть задача перевернуть матрицу на 90 градусов.

```
 [1, 2, 3]    [7, 4, 1]
 [4, 5, 6] -> [8, 5, 2]  
 [7, 8, 9]    [9, 6, 3]
```

Почему эти решения дают разный результат?
1:

```
const matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
function rotate(source) {
  const res = new Array(source[0].length).fill([])
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < source[0].length; j++) {
      res[j][source.length - 1 - i] = source[i][j]
    }
  }

  return res
}

console.log(rotate(matrix))
```

результат:

```
[
  [9, 6, 3],
  [9, 6, 3],
  [9, 6, 3]
]
```

но когда пишем так(изменилась только 2 строка):

```
function rotate2(source) {
  const res1 = source[0].map(() => [])
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < source[0].length; j++) {
      res1[j][source.length - 1 - i] = source[i][j]
    }
  }

  return res1
}
```

результат верный:

```
[
[7, 4, 1]
[8, 5, 2]  
[9, 6, 3] 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), заполняет элементы **одним и тем же** массивом.

Поэтому при выводе значения одинаковые по строкам.

В случае с `.map` - каждый раз создается новый массив.

Comment: Но и в том и в другом случае получается заготовка состоящая из пустых массивов. Такая: [[],[],[],]

Comment: @АлёнаБабанкова, в ответе как раз об этом речь. В первом случае - это ссылка на один и тот же массив, во втором - на разные. При выводе они могут выглядеть одинаково при этом.

Comment: поняла!спасибо!